# How to make visible circle around button on focus only using Qt StyleSheet

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

Given the stylesheet for a button:

[image]

```
top: 960px;
left: 944px;
width: 40px;
height: 40px; 
background: transparent url('img/play_circle_filled-24px-2.png') 0% 0% no-repeat;
padding-box; opacity: 1;
```

and the stylesheet for a circle around it:

```
top: 944px;
left: 928px;
width: 72px;
height: 72px;
background: #EEEEEE 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
opacity: 0.2;
```

how to make the circle visible on focus only? Is it possible inside one stylesheet (QAbstractButton{) or it'll need to use some QLabel additionally for this task?
I'm totally incompetent in css, so I'm here to ask you.

P.S
The following stylesheet makes almost what I want except it doesn't draw circle but square.

```
"QAbstractButton {"
"top: 960px;"
"left: 944px;"
"width: 40px;"
"height: 40px;"
"border-image: url('img/play_circle_filled-24px-2.png') 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;"
"opacity: 1;"
"}"

"QAbstractButton:focus {"
"border-radius: 72px;"
"background-color: blue ;"
"opacity: 0.2;"
"}"
```

Comment: How does the html of the button and the circle look like? Is the button the child of the circle? Has it to be this way?

Comment: It's not html web programming, it's Qt desktop programming. It has css too, but it's not 100% compatible. But, maybe it can be a child, if it'll look like what I want it doesn't matter.

Comment: @alxprogger Do not use the [tag:css] tag as it has another objective, in these cases it is better to use [tag:qtstylesheets]

Answer (score 0):

You can use outline property in css.

HTML:

```
<div class="img_outline">
    <button class="outline-button">Button</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .outline-button:focus{
           border:none;
           outline: 3px solid #4CAF50;
     }
```

You can also add "outline-offset:20px" in ".outline__photo" class, if you want a space between the border and image.
It worked for me.